# What is an equivalent Struts2 code for below snippet?

Tags: struts2

I want to migrate below code to Struts2.

```
<input type="button" value="<bdb:msg id='button.title'/>"
       onClick="forward('showLocation','<c:out value="${locationForm.bkn}"/>');" style="">
```

I tried using **s:submit** but not able to send "locationForm.bkn" parameter with it. It is possible with *s:url* & *s:a* tags but my requirement is to do it with buttons.

Also, the value attribute of input tag must be passed through **bdb:msg** tag which is a custom tag.

Can I get a help here?

Comment: As I see it - if you want to keep some custom tags (`bdb:msg`), and also use java script to submit a request  (`onclick=fowrward(..)`) ... then the only thing left to change to `struts2` here is `<c:out>` tag - so use `<s:property >` instead ...

Comment: @Plirkee I already tried using <s:property>. When I click the button, no action is happening.

Comment: Well I guess it is because of your `javascript` function called `forward` ...